# Error - pointing domain name to EC2 using NGINX to run ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

I have some issues on the EC2
I have a react-node JS web app running on an EC2 instance.
The app is running on http://44.200.69.97/ and everything is fine with it but the issue when I tried to point my domain name to it, it failed.
The domain name is http://dev.censorit.net/

The http://dev.censorit.net/ should point to http://44.200.69.97/ but it's not.

When I specify the port it works,
http://dev.censorit.net:3000/ points to http://44.200.69.97:3000

The domain not pointing to port 80 but points to any other port

I tried moving the build files into root /var/www/html; but didn't work. Then I tried reversed proxy and it didn't work as well.

I'm using NGINX and this is the conf file

```
upstream app_reactjs {
   server localhost:3000;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name dev.censorit.net;

   location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
     proxy_pass http://app_reactjs;
     proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want redirect to the IP address?

Comment: Yes, I need the domain name to point to the IP ??

Comment: Pointing is not the same as redirecting. When you point your domain (canonical name) to the IP, it will remain in address bar of the browser.
BTW I can see that it works for both 80 and 3000 ports.

Comment: sorry, I meant pointing. dev.censorit.net shows me the an error page from hostinger not my app

Comment: try `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` instead of ` proxy_pass http://app_reactjs;` and also remove that `upstream` directive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the hosting service to amazon and changed the DNS nameserver to amazon